# Hover function within flex box

Tags: html, css

Im doing a hover function within my nav link atribute, and it shows the color only on one side of the word I've written. [Pointer hovering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LblMl.png)

I created a flexbox and within that box I added links that represents buttons. don't know if I've done something wrong?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #434343;
}

li,
a {
  font-family: apple braille;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav__links li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 40px 50px 0px;
}

.nav__links li a {
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav__links li a:hover {
  color: #c70039
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="nav__links">
    <li><a href="#">Map.<a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About.<a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproduction here with the relevant HTML?

Comment: It should be up now

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem with the code you've given. (There is an obvious error in the HTML that https://validator.nu/ would pick up though)

Comment: I searched my code on the program and found some smaller problems with my end tags on <a>. But Nothing helped with my problem. Could it be something with my CSS?

Comment: Yes, but without a [mcve] we can't do much.